# Firebase function is not triggering

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo

I am using expo-payments-stripe API for the payment of an android app. And Stripe payment API is getting called from the following firebase function:

```
exports.payWithStripe = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    stripe.charges.create({
        amount: request.body.amount,
        currency: request.body.currency,
        source: request.body.token,
    }).then((charge) => {
            response.send(charge);
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        });

});
```

Here is the code for the client-side that calls the firebase functions:

```
payment = async () => {
    if (this.state.token) {
      fetch(
        "https://us-central1-<>.cloudfunctions.net/payWithStripe",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            amount: this.state.amount,
            currency: "usd",
            token: this.state.token.tokenId,
          }),
        }
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          if (
            responseJson.status === "succeeded" &&
            responseJson.paid == true
          ) {
           
            this.setState({ status: "succeeded", loading: false });
          }
          console.log(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.setState({ status: "failed", loading: false });
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  };
```

```
doPayment = async () => {
    const params = {
      number: this.state.number,
      expMonth: parseInt(this.state.expMonth),
      expYear: parseInt(this.state.expYear),
      cvc: this.state.cvc,
    };
    const token = await Stripe.createTokenWithCardAsync(params);
    this.setState({ token: token, loading: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.payment();
    }, 5000);
    console.log(token);
  };
```

Everything works fine in the test mode. But after deploying the app to the Play store Firebase function is not triggered. Any suggestions on why this might be happening? Also without ejecting expo what other options do I have to make payments from expo react native app for android?

Comment: You don't get any error ? put crashlytics message or sentry

Comment: How do you trigger your Cloud Function? Can you share the code which does that? Also, how do you know it is not triggered? You need to share all these details for us to be able to understand your problem.

Comment: I just added the client-side code that triggers the firebase function. Also, I know the firebase function is not triggered because if the function were triggered then it would have been showing in the firebase function log console. In the test mode firebase function log console shows that function is triggered successfully, but in the live mode, it doesn't show anything @Renaud Tarnec

Comment: No, I don't get any error. After calling the firebase function, nothing happens. @anthony willis muñoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check adding await to the fetch or removing async from the payment function? Also why did you add setTimeout to the payment function call?

Comment: Details, language, context, and a snippet of code are included in the original post @Haider Malik

Comment: I tried adding await on the fetch as you suggested. It still doesn't work. Now I'm thinking about creating a webpage to make the payment and link the webpage from the app with Webview. @Scott